# Set font style without System.Drawing

Tags: c#, silverlight, system.drawing

I'm facing a awkward problem. I can't set the FontStyle of a text. This is annoying me cause until now I'm not able to understand why the `System. Drawing` is missing, why I can't import her (At least I think I shouldn't).

The context is I'm in a silverlight application, setting the font color and style of a dynamic tree.

I'm using `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` to the Foreground, but I trying to set the FontStyle without success. And all google that I try answer the simple: 'use System.Drawing'

What I'm missing here?

Comment: "I can't set the FontStyle of a text". Is it a compilation error? a runtime error? Please explain precisely what you expect, what you observe and what you have tried.

Comment: Is compilation error
Basically I can set a `new FontStyle();` without parameters
and when I try to use the field I can use get the object features, like `GetHashCode`, `ToString`

Comment: Please post your code and explain what is failing in it.

Comment: @Oded, the is no code. Basically I can't write: `FontStyle f = FontStyle.Italic`

Comment: @Oded, It's a RadTreeViewItem (telerik), they have the FontStyle property. But seems that I can't use the System.Drawing with silverlight or something like that. Is it true?

Comment: Did you import `System.Windows`? It has a [`FontStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602623) class. `FontStyles f = FontStyles.Italic` should work.

Comment: perfect! I was in a trick from Resharper. It was always suggesting to use `FontStyle`, so I click enter and I entered in loop again. With `FontStyles` it worked. Sorry about this question. I was almost starting to drive crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to create a new FontStyle struct, but use the static properties of FontStyles: `FontStyles.Italic` or `FontStyles.Normal`.

Comment: Can you tell me what library are you suggesting? If it's System.Drawing, this is the exactly problem with my question is referring. I'm not able to access this library for some reason.

Comment: It is System.Windows. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontstyle(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontstyle(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: I tried several times, but Resharper was always suggesting to use `FontStyle`, so I click enter and I entered in loop again. With `FontStyles` it worked.

Comment: Yes, well you're still using FontStyle, you're just getting an instance of it from `FontStyles`. Glad it worked anyway!